# Using C++ iterator find() to find pointer to certain value

Tags: c++, pointers, iterator, find

I am trying to use an iterator find() to retrieve the pointer to a node class that contains a certain value.

Is there a better way than doing something like this?

```
typedef vector<Node*> Vmap; 
Vmap vmap;

for(Vmap::iterator itr = vmap.begin(); itr != vmap.end(); itr++) {
    if((*itr)->getVal() == 3) {
         // do something
    }
}
```

Desired:

```
Vmap::iterator itr = find(vmap.begin(), vmap.end, 3) // return Node pointer with value == 3

Node* temp_node = *itr
```

Thank you

EDIT: Additional information to supplement given answer.

[What is a lambda expression in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627098/what-is-a-lambda-expression-in-c11)

Comment: Poorly researched! There are numerous duplicate-questions to be found. `find_if()` and  a lambda expression just does the trick.

Comment: I did do research, but couldn't find the answer with my limited vocabulary of c++

Answer (score 2):

```
Vmap::iterator itr = std::find_if(vmap.begin(), vmap.end(),
  [](Node* node) { return node->getVal() == 3; } );
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `std::find_if`:

```
auto itr = std::find_if(vmap.begin(),
                        vmap.end(),
                        [](const Node* node) { return node->getVal() == 3;});
```